# how to configure default gateway

Tags: routing, gateway, rhel6

On a RHEL6 server I added a 2nd nic and have configured it to use a static ip on a different subnet.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.157.32   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     1      0        0 eth1
128.83.188.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.157.33   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

However, /etc/sysconfig/network states:

```
GATEWAY=128.83.188.193
```

Why is this statement getting ignored?

I can manually change the default route using the `ip` or `route` command, but when I restart the network, the default route still goes back to eth1.

Comment: Just a tip: you could change default gw with one command - "ip ro change default via 128.83.188.193"

Comment: But I want the change to be permanent.

Comment: Oh, right, you just meant that I could do this instead of using two route commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line

```
GATEWAY=128.83.188.193
```

in to the /etc/sysconfig/network. Also check that there is no default gw in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network already had the line `GATEWAY=128.83.188.193` in it.  I had already tried to to removing the `GATEWAY` statement from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1, but when I do that, the routing table shows the gateway at 128.83.188.193, but it shows the interface at eth1, and my network seems borked (can't see outside world or ssh in).

Comment: It's worth having a read of the [RHEL Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/index.html) for finding out how to do these things.

Comment: I have done what the deployment guide has recommended.  It says that /etc/sysconfig/network contains the GATEWAY option, which sets the network's gateway.  This option was already set correctly, but it seems to be getting ignored.

Comment: I have been seen the system where default gw was defined in ifcfg-ethX. Also check /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1 if one exist

Comment: @ALex_hha As noted, I removed the GATEWAY option from ifcfg-eth1, but when I did this, it changed the default gateway ip to the correct value, but it left the interface at eth1.  This seems to have had an ill effect on my network.

Comment: What do you mean by - "but it left the interface at eth1" ? Could you clarify what exactly doesn't work after all changes that you have done?

Comment: @ALex_hha Sorry, yeah, I meant that when I do a `route -n`, under _destination_ it says `0.0.0.0` under _gateway_ it says `128.83.188.193`, and under _Iface_ `eth1`.  When it is setup this way, I can't ssh in, and my browser doesn't work.  If however, I make the changes with `route add default gw...`, `route -n` says `eth0` under _Iface_ and everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: (mini-markdown doesn't seem to allow me to put the output here in a helpful format)

Comment: It would be best to add such info into the first post

Answer (score 0):

When I entered the parameters for the new interface, I made the interface "available to all users".  If I delete the interface and add it back without making it available to all users, the gateway stays at eth0.